# Laravel 5 queue job freezes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm implementing a command that will process uploaded files.

The files can contain up to 300MB of data, so the job needs to be queued and I also expect that it takes a while to complete.

My problem is, when I run `php artisan queue:listen` it gets the job from the queue, starts processing it normally but after around 20 seconds, it freezes. The job doesn't launch any exception and neither continues so its not removed from the queue.

I'm using the `database` driver. Am is missing something here?

Comment: Without seeing the code, It's hard to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan queue:listen` does not output the errors for the user. Run `php artisan queue:work` and it will output the errors. This command will only run one process in the queue. So you need to make sure that the next process is the one you want to debug.

Comment: It also freezes. I found my "error". It's a kind of bug. `fgetcsv` after reading a lot of lines, returns null instead of `FALSE`. So I was in an infinite loop.

Comment: How many lines? It's possible that you exhausted the memory limit. Try adding this statement `ini_set('memory_limit', -1);` on top of your code. This will remove the memory limit of your php.

Comment: 7000 lines. This is very weird because I was using `SplFileInfo`. With that way, somewhere it returned `null` when I was expecting `false` for an error or end of file. So I changed it to use the common `fopen` way. With this way I actually read all the file and receive `false` at the end of file. The problem is that not all the lines are read. Around 10% is not read. Very weird. Thinking in opening another question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it does not freezes, but it seems like it froze when you see nothing happening in command line interface after you run  php artisan queue:work or php artisan queue:listen  command.

As in my case,

// Execute Laravel queues by queue names on coomand line interface->

I was using running command
**php artisan queue:work**
which was not running my queued jobs in jobs table.

Then i relaized, it was only working for jobs with queue column value = 'default'
and  i had given names like sendemail, inboxemail etc.

So when i changed this other value to  'default'  in queue column in jobs table,
this job ran instantly as i have opended cli and  php artisan queue:work
command was active.

So if you want to run only a specific queue by queue name, run command ->

**php artisan queue:listen --queue=sendemail**

or

**php artisan queue:listen --queue=inboxemail**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone making the same mistake as I did, **DO NOT CREATE TABLES BASED ON THE "JOBS" TABLE!**

Its not a memory leak or sth. I had another table "`job_info`" with a foreign key referring to the `jobs` table; As it turned out laravel wasn't able to remove the job from the table after it's done successfully (as it normally do). That's because it would break the relationships in the database. So it'd keep retrying until max attempts exceeded leading to an exception with no information about the actual problem.